# Setting OAuth2 token for RestTemplate in an app that uses both @ResourceServer and @EnableOauth2Sso

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

On my current project I have an app that has a small graphical piece that users authenticate using SSO, and a portion that is purely API where users authenticate using an Authorization header.

For example:

- `/ping-other-service` is accessed using SSO.
- `/api/ping-other-service` is accessed using a bearer token

Being all cloud native our app communicates with other services that uses the same SSO provider using JWT tokens ([UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa)), so I figured we'd use `OAuth2RestTemplate` since [according to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-custom-user-info-client) it can magically insert the authentication credentials. It does do that for all endpoints that are authenticated using SSO. But when we use an endpoint that is authed through bearer token it doesn't populate the rest template.

My understanding [from the documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableOAuth2Client.java#L28-L32) is that `@EnableOAuth2Client` will only extract the token from a SSO login, not auth header?

## What I'm seeing

Failed request and what it does:

1. `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" http://localhost/api/ping-other-service`
2. Internally uses restTemplate to call http://some-other-service/ping which responds 401

Successful request and what it does:

1. Chrome http://localhost/ping-other-service
2. Internally uses restTemplate to call http://some-other-service/ping which responds 200

## How we worked around it

To work around this I ended up creating the following monstrosity which will extract the token from the `OAuth2ClientContext` if it isn't available from an authorization header.

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/ping-other-service")
    public ResponseEntity ping(@PathVariable String caseId, HttpServletRequest request, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        try {
            restTemplate.postForEntity(adapterUrl + "/webhook/ping", getRequest(request), Map.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private HttpEntity<?> getRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + getRequestToken(request));
        return new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    }

    private String getRequestToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Authentication token = new BearerTokenExtractor().extract(request);
        if (token != null) {
            return (String) token.getPrincipal();
        } else {
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = oAuth2ClientContext.getAccessToken();

            if (accessToken != null) {
                return accessToken.getValue();
            }
        }

        throw new ResourceNotFound("No valid access token found");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `/api/**` resources there is an incoming token, but because you are using JWT the resource server can authenticate without calling out to the auth server, so there is no `OAuth2RestTemplate` just sitting around waiting for you to re-use the context in the token relay (if you were using `UserInfoTokenServices` there would be one). You can create one though quite easily, and pull the incoming token out of the `SecurityContext`. Example:

```
  @Autowired
  private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource;

  private OAuth2RestTemplate tokenRelayTemplate(Principal principal) {
    OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
    OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
    details.getTokenValue();
    OAuth2ClientContext context = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(details.getTokenValue()));
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, context);
  }
```

You could probably turn that method into `@Bean` (in `@Scope("request")`) and inject the template with a `@Qualifier` if you wanted.

There's some autoconfiguration and a utility class to help with this pattern in [Spring Cloud Security](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security), e.g: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/blob/master/spring-cloud-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/security/oauth2/client/AccessTokenContextRelay.java

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'll give this a try tomorrow at work! :)

Will this work seamlessly for the `restTemplate` or would I need to define one restTemplate for `/api` paths and one for the others? (one other requirement is that anyone that got a logged in session also can call the API without the token and rely on the session (which is configured and working except for the rest template))

Comment: That method can be "bean-ified" if you remove the principle parameter and get the authentication from the current security context. So "OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()"

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when developing a Spring resource server, and I needed to pass the OAuth2 token from a request to the restTemplate for a call to a  downstream resource server. Both resource servers use the same auth server, and I found Dave's link helpful but I had to dig a bit to find out how to implement this. I ended up finding the documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/blob/a857a2e66d327cdb5877d4e4bd703f1a5662a10f/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-security.adoc#resource-server-token-relay), and it turn's out the implemetation was very simple. I was using `@EnableOAuth2Client`, so I had to create the `restTemplate` bean with the injected `OAuth2ClientContext` and create the appropriate resource details. In my case it was `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails`. Thanks for all great work Dave!

```
@Bean 
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate (OAuth2ClientContext context) {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    // Configure the details here
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dave Syer
My UAA service is also an oauth2 client, which needs to relay JWT tokens coming in from Zuul. When configuring the oauth2 client the following way

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RibbonClient(name = "downstream")
public class OAuthClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext context) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, context);
    }
}
```

I do get a 401 response from the downstream service as my access token has a very short validity and the `AccessTokenContextRelay` does not update an incoming access token (Zuul does renew expired access tokens by the refresh token).

The `OAuth2RestTemplate#getAccessToken` will never acquire a new access token as the `isExpired` on the access token stored by the `AccessTokenContextRelay` drops the validity and refresh token information.

How can this by solved?